# How to use Html Anchor <a> to send AJAX Post Request

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I am using the following  tag to let the users like the post

```
<a href="#" class="like" id="like_22">Like</a>
```

I get the id of the `<a>` through Javascript which is actually the post_id and send the data to `like.php` using the following `GET` method.

```
 post_id = 22;
 xrequest.open("GET","like.php?post_id="+post_id+",true);
 xrequest.send();
```

I have two questions

1. How can I send this request using `POST` Method?
   (Note that there is not any `<form>...</form>` around the  tag.)
2. If I use the above mentioned GET Method, Is it secure?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you've tagged jQuery, I assume you are using it. If so, you can do it like:

```
// attach a click handler for all links with class "like"
$('a.like').click(function() {

    // use jQuery's $.post, to send the request
    // the second argument is the request data
    $.post('like.php', {post_id: this.id}, function(data) {
        // data is what your server returns
    });

    // prevent the link's default behavior
    return false;
});
```

Regarding your second question: **No**, it does not really make it safer unless you are doing it within SSL (https). a middle-man can still intercept your message mid-way and read the contents. POST makes it more indirect (to intercept and read the payload) than GET, but not safer.

Answer (score 1):

To use POST to send the like link id you can do the following:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("a.like").click(function(event) {
        var data = event.target.id;
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "like.php",
        data: data
        });
    });
    });
```

updated, there was a typo in my code.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question correctly, something like this should work for you:

```
$('#link_22').click(function(){
    var link = $(this).attr('id');
    $.post('/like.php/', {post_id: link});
    return false;

})
```

Then you can reach this from PHP with something like:

```
$_POST['post_id'];
```